# Problem importing from blender to unreal engine 4

Tags: object, import, blender, unreal-engine4, game-development

I have a problem with importing files from blender to ue4.

I made a [carpet](https://ibb.co/LZP78p6) in blender, but when I import my object to unreal engine 4, I get this:

[image: following]

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you did not export the object from Blender correctly. Most of the time I have seen this that is the issue. Here is a reference that might help:
https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/769132/importing-assets-from-blender-to-ue4.html

Other times, I just had to reset the static mesh's settings in the view. It sometimes forgets what material instance it is supposed to go with.